# Docker -- How to mount directory as volume on boot (in MacOS)

Tags: macos, docker

What is a very simple, one-line terminal command to mount a local directory as a volume for a Docker container everytime it boots (in MacOS)?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean. You know that containers don't just start on their own (Unless you will use a serivce/script/cron/run etc).

You add volume by using -v/--volume option:

`docker run -dit --name=FOO -v /Path/On/Host:/Path/In/Container Image`

If you want to have it on boot you need probably a service (although I' don't know if they are available on mac)

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo Bar
After=docker.service
BindsTo=docker.service
Conflicts=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Environment=LOCAL_DIR='/Path/On/Host'
Environment=TARGET_DIR='/Path/On/Container'
Environment=IMAGE='YOUR_DOCKER_IMAGE'
TimeoutStartSec=0
TimeoutStopSec=30
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm -f Foo_Bar

ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -dit --name=Foo_Bar -v $LOCAL_DIR:$TARGET_DIR $IMAGE

ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop Foo_Bar 
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```